# How to avoid code duplication when running NUXT.js and Axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

If similar code (as in the example) is duplicated in different components but with slight differences in the name of what I pass in the function parameters

What are the options to take the code somewhere separately and then introduce that into my components with custom parameters?
(individually for each component)

Should I do this through a plugin?
If so, then how can I implement the individually necessary parameters on the components + how to connect the plugin only on these components and nowhere else?

Comment: You don't need to do that since every request is different and most importantly you will do something else when the request is success or fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For axios calls, you can create a function or class and import it every time

Something like `services/axios`

```js
import axios from 'axios';


const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        accept: 'Accept: application/json',
    },
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

And then in `utils/requests`

```js
import axiosInstance from '@/services/axios';

const apiRequest = async (axiosConfig) => {
  try {
      const response = await axiosInstance(axiosConfig);
      return {
        success: true,
        data: response.data.data || response.data;
      }
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
       error = error.response
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
       error = error.request
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
       error = error.message
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
      return {
        success: false,
        error
      }
  }
};

export const getRequest = async (url) =>
    await apiRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url,
    });

export const postRequest = async(url, requestBody) =>
    await apiRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url,
        data: requestBody
    });
```

You then import the getRequest and postRequest methods in the components

#### component.vue

```js
import { getRequest, postRequest } from '@/utils/requests';

 
const response = await postRequest('/url', requestBody);
 
if (response.success) {
   // do stuff on success
 } else {
  // error message
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do it by mixins. Make a js file inside mixins folder and put this function there and add this mixin file in vue files to use this function.

Answer (score 1):

I used [nuxt/axios.js](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/) for my nuxt app. You can use it as a plugin.

In plugins folder, make a file `axios.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
   baseURL: process.env.baseURL,
})
```

NOTE: I am storing the base url of the server to be called for APIs in environment variables using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) lib. And this way, the base url is set for all the calls to be made.

Then import it in `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
....
{
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],

  axios: {
  ...
  },
}
```

TIP: If you have to store a value in axios like "token" or "cookie" globally. Then you can use axios [defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults) method

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = { Authorization: `bearer ${token}` };
```