# nuxt js acces to component data from server side

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Is there any way to access from serverside to component data or props ?

I have test app with test component with template

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>TEST PAGE</h1>
  <p>counter : {{counter}}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

In asyncData()  I start a timer

```
asyncData(context)
{
  console.log('in server process')
    console.log(context)
    let timerId = setInterval(() => {

     ..... some logic
    }, 4000);
    return {counter : 15};
  },
}
```

SO question, how posible change the counter value dynamicaly in template? I need do it on server side for some reason
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`asyncData` method runs way earlier and only once before loading of the page. It is performed before initialization of the component.

*reference*: [Nuxt Lifecycle](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/),
[asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data)

*Solution*:

You can `watch` the property and send an async request (using libraries like axios / fetch) to let the server know and handle it on the server.

Comment: Are you mean rest call ? Because I need change data of componetns after it`s mount event.

Comment: Yeah if that's the protocol you are following. 
If you need help making an axios call you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207552/how-to-avoid-code-duplication-when-running-nuxt-js-and-axios/63208013#63208013)

Comment: Is there any way to make easily rest backend in nuxt.js  or built it one ? If I try build code on page section it covers with it`s template, but in this case I nedd pure json output.

Comment: Check here: [https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make an API call to your backend during AsyncData lifecycle. You can refer to this [Nuxt example here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/) .

`Returning a Promise`

```
export default {
  asyncData( context ) {
    return axios.get(`https://my-api/counter`).then(res => {
      return { counter: res.data.counter}
    })
  }
}
```